# How to set a deleted property to true rather than removing a related doctrine entity in Symfony

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm building an app that allows a user to create reports for advertisers.  The entities are set up so that there is a relation between the Report object and the Advertiser object - so that the advertiser has a getReports() method to get them.

I would like to change the app so that instead of actually deleting entities, that it simply changes a "deleted" property to true.  That part is no problem, but I'm unsure how to make it so that the getReports() on the Advertiser entity only returns reports for the advertiser that have a deleted property of false.

Please let me know if you have any suggestions how that should be done in accordance with Symfony best practices.

Comment: Do you have the need to get also the "deleted" reports of an Advertiser? Or to keep the relation between the Advertiser and the deleted Reports?

Comment: No, I don't need to be able to get the deleted reports, but could manually flip the deleted flag in the database to get it back if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look into Gedmo Doctrine Extensions. http://atlantic18.github.io/DoctrineExtensions/

Specifically for your case:
http://atlantic18.github.io/DoctrineExtensions/doc/softdeleteable.html

TLDR; they allow you to configure behavior of your entities in a way you desire, so for example when you "delete" an entity, Gedmo's listeners would set it's `deleted` value to a current datetime. Now you'd still have that record in your database but with `not null` value of `deleted` column marking it 'soft deleted', so when querying, it wouldn't be returned (because Doctrine knows how to query these stuff and would add a condition i.e.: `... where deleted ...`) unless you explicitly say you want to see those soft deleted records.

Comment: That looks interesting, but it doesn't appear that has been updated in a few years: 2016-01-27.

Comment: I think Symfony still recommends this bundle.

Comment: My bad - it looks like on this page it shows it was updated in 2018,  I'll try using this bundle.  https://packagist.org/packages/gedmo/doctrine-extensions

Comment: Getting that working in Symfony 4 seems like an uphill battle.  I was following the instructions in this page https://blog.joeymasip.com/gedmo-translations-in-symfony-4/ and found that the stof_doctrine_extensions.yaml file they reference doesn't get created with the recipe - and when I apply the doctrine.yml changes they mention, the app is no longer working.  There doesn't seem to be documentation on the Atlantic18 site (or anywhere I can find) on how to set this up in Symfony 4.

Comment: I also tried installing it as described here https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/installation.html#installation-using-symfony-flex but my Symfony 4 project does not have a file called app/AppKernel.php.  I'm not sure if this is only for older versions of symfony or something.

Comment: I was able to finally get the StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle installed properly.  The problem with the install was I needed to set "allow-contrib": true for symfony in my composer.json.  This article pointed me to the solution: https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/issues/365

Comment: Glad to hear that. That option tells Symfony Flex to allow usage of community contributed recipes, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, Domagoj!  After changing the value of allow-contrib and following the instructions in this post https://rojas.io/creating-a-web-app-with-symfony-4-doctrine-entities/ it is working!

Comment: No problem. Happy coding :)